# How to open in new window using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code. How can I open this url in new window?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = new Date,
        t = (e.getDate(), e.getMonth()),
        l = e.getFullYear(),
        a = $("#calendar").fullCalenda‌​ r({
            header: {
                left: "prev,next today",
                center: "title",
                right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
            },
            defaultView: "month",
            se‌lectable: !0,
            selectHelper: !0,
            select: function(e, t, l) {
                var n = prompt("Event Title:");
                n && a.fullCalendar("renderEvent", {
                    title: n,
                    start: e,
                    end: t,
                    allDay: l
                }, !0), a.‌fullCalendar("unselect")
            },
            editable: !0,
            events: [{
                title: "Click for Google",
                start: new Date(l, t, 28),
                end: new Date(l, t, 29),
                url: "google.com/";
            }]
        })
});
```

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java

Comment: Provide the complete code snippet. Is that a JSON?

Comment: @AmalTs, it appears to be part of a literal object statement, as it has function calls in it

Comment: But can you share the complete statement? This one ends with comma and is not a statement.

Comment: @ Amal Ts. this is an event calendar code

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to create a custom eventClick callback to control the click event (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) then you should be able to use something like window.open to open the desired URL in a new window.

Seriously though, saying which plugin you're using would be a good start, and maybe a little more in the way of background about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete. But lets see if this is what you are looking for:

Example if ur events can be stored in a var, then:

```
var a = { events: [{ 'title': 'NWS-2015','start': "",'end': "",'url': 'https://www.google.co.in/'}] };
window.open(a.events[0].url,"_blank");
```

this will open ur link in new window